# Create PHP array from letters

Tags: awk, sed, php, string, array

I would like to create a PHP array from the Serbian alphabet.

Out of

```
а б в г д ђ е ж з и ј к л љ м н њ о п р с т ћ у ф х ц ч џ ш
a b c č ć d dž đ e f g h i j k l lj m n nj o p r s š t u v z ž
```

should become this (a custom array):

```
'а': 'a',
'б': 'b',
'в': 'c',
'г': 'č',
'д': 'ć',
```

How can I do this with awk or sed?

Comment: The correspondence between the two sets is off though...

Comment: @don_crissti by number of characters yes, but by "words" - ie, space separated items, no the same number. Some of teh single characters in upper line are represented by 2 characters in lower line.

Comment: @ivanivan - I'm not talking about the no. of "words" I'm talking about the correspondence between them, if you read the question and check the expected output (including the answers below) you'll understand...

Comment: Luis, if any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This gets pretty close:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 { for( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {out[i][0]=$i } } NR==2 { for( i=1; i<=NF; i++) {out[i][1]=$i }  } END {for( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) { print "\""out[i][0]"\":\""out[i][1]"\","}}' input
"а":"a",
"б":"b",
"в":"c",
"г":"č",
"д":"ć",
"ђ":"d",
"е":"dž",
"ж":"đ",
"з":"e",
"и":"f",
"ј":"g",
"к":"h",
"л":"i",
"љ":"j",
"м":"k",
"н":"l",
"њ":"lj",
"о":"m",
"п":"n",
"р":"nj",
"с":"o",
"т":"p",
"ћ":"r",
"у":"s",
"ф":"š",
"х":"t",
"ц":"u",
"ч":"v",
"џ":"z",
"ш":"ž",
```

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` using its `${a:^b}` *array zipping* operator:

```
{read -A a; read -A b} < your-file-with-those-2-lines.txt
printf "'%s': '%s',\n" ${a:^b}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using AWK:

```
awk '                                  
BEGIN { OFS="'"': '"'";start=1 }       
NR>=start && $0!="" {                  
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                 
        a[i]=a[i] (NR==start?"":OFS) $i
    }
END {                                  
    for(j=1;j<i;j++)                   
        print "'"'"'"a[j]"'"',"'"                     
}' file.txt
```

**Output**

```
'а': 'a',
'б': 'b',
'в': 'c',
'г': 'č',
'д': 'ć',
```

Answer (score 1):

In bash, with parallel arrays:

```
$ read -a src < <(sed -n 1p input)
$ read -a dest < <(sed -n 2p input)
$ for((i=0; i < "${#src[@]}"; i++))
do
  printf "'%s': '%s',\n" "${src[i]}" "${dest[i]}"
done
```

The output is:

```
'а': 'a',
'б': 'b',
'в': 'c',
'г': 'č',
'д': 'ć',
'ђ': 'd',
'е': 'dž',
'ж': 'đ',
'з': 'e',
'и': 'f',
'ј': 'g',
'к': 'h',
'л': 'i',
'љ': 'j',
'м': 'k',
'н': 'l',
'њ': 'lj',
'о': 'm',
'п': 'n',
'р': 'nj',
'с': 'o',
'т': 'p',
'ћ': 'r',
'у': 's',
'ф': 'š',
'х': 't',
'ц': 'u',
'ч': 'v',
'џ': 'z',
'ш': 'ž',
```

Answer (score 1):

```
printf  "'%s' : '%s',\n" $(datamash -W transpose < input.txt)
```

**Input**

```
а б в г д ђ е ж з и ј к л љ м н њ о п р с т ћ у ф х ц ч џ ш
a b c č ć d dž đ e f g h i j k l lj m n nj o p r s š t u v z ž
```

**Output**

```
'а' : 'a',
'б' : 'b',
'в' : 'c',
'г' : 'č',
'д' : 'ć',
'ђ' : 'd',
'е' : 'dž',
'ж' : 'đ',
'з' : 'e',
'и' : 'f',
'ј' : 'g',
'к' : 'h',
'л' : 'i',
'љ' : 'j',
'м' : 'k',
'н' : 'l',
'њ' : 'lj',
'о' : 'm',
'п' : 'n',
'р' : 'nj',
'с' : 'o',
'т' : 'p',
'ћ' : 'r',
'у' : 's',
'ф' : 'š',
'х' : 't',
'ц' : 'u',
'ч' : 'v',
'џ' : 'z',
'ш' : 'ž',
```

Answer (score 1):

You ask for `awk` but you want to create PHP array, so I figured I'd give you a PHP way of doing it - and yes, you can run PHP from command line...

Stick your 2 lines into a file

```
а б в г д ђ е ж з и ј к л љ м н њ о п р с т ћ у ф х ц ч џ ш
a b c č ć d dž đ e f g h i j k l lj m n nj o p r s š t u v z ž
```

And then read that file with `file()` which brings each line into an element in an array.

Then loop through that array, breaking each line into its own array based on space separation using `explode()`

Then loop through your 2 lines and rebuild an associative array.

I do notice the last character in the first line seems to bring along a new line character, but that could be an encoding issue... not familiar enough with working with foreign character sets.

```
<?php

$letters=file("letters");

for($i=0;$i<count($letters);$i++){
    $line[$i]=explode(" ",$letters[$i]);
}

for($i=0;$i<count($line[1]);$i++){
        $newArray[$line[0][$i]]=$line[1][$i];
}

print_r($newArray);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==1 { printf "%s\n",'$0' }' input.txt | tr ' ' '\n' &amp;gt; a.txt
awk 'NR== 2{ printf "%s\n",'$0' }' input.txt | tr ' ' '\n' &amp;gt;. b.txt
paste -d : a b
```